# Can I create an App Identifier Configuration without In-App-Purchase capability?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to create a bundle Id without In-App-Purchase, but in-app-Purchase is showing checked by default. I'm unable to uncheck it.
My app is free for iOS.

Comment: Are you referring to the checkbox in Appstore Connect or in Xcode?

Comment: I want to create Bundle Identifier from developer account. I think previously we can create Bundle Identifier by unchecked in-app- purchase, but now it's showing  inbuilt checked in-app purchase while creating Bundle Identifier from developer account.

Answer (score 0):

The "In-App Purchase" capability in the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" editor on developer.apple.com is on by default and cannot be removed.

However, your app will still be free.

Comment: yes, but when I upload app on App Store I got "pending agreement" status on app

Comment: @Shital that has nothing to do with the In-App-Purchase capability in your app configuration. Check the suggestions from here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121261